# Why do you divide by two when checking prime numbers in Java?

Tags: java

I was looking over this on YouTube and saw some code. I got most of it but didn't understand at all the reason why you the value n divide by two. Could someone please explain it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Primes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(findPrimes(1, 100));
        
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Integer> findPrimes(int start, int end) {
        
        ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for(int n = start; n < end; n++) {
            boolean prime = true;
            
            int i = 2; 
            while(i <= n/2) {
                if(n % i == 0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            
            if(prime) {
                primes.add(n);
            }
        }
        
        return primes;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because you can be sure that if a number is higher than half the number you're checking there's no way you can multiply it by any integer and get the number you're looking for, so you can ignore those numbers.

Comment: Or to put it into a concrete example: If you want to check if 434553 is a prime number, you can be sure that no value bigger than 217276 can ever be a prime factor (since multiplying 217277 by 2 (the smallest other possible factor) already produces a number that's bigger than our original). If you **don't** divide by two, the result won't be wrong, but you'll be doing double the work for no benefit.

Answer (score 3):

A number can only be divided by a number that is less than or equal to its half. Or the number to be divided itself.

Comment: That explains `if(n % i == 0)`, which will include the case of i==2, but not `while(i <= n/2)`. I believe the latter should be `while (i <= Math.sqrt(n))`.

Comment: @jsheeran consider 44. Isn't it divisible by 22? Isn't `22 <= 44 / 2`? Why would I care about the square root of 44?

Comment: Well, `44/22 == 2`, but then it is also true that `44/2 == 22`. Which is checked in the first iteration. Also, `n/2 > sqrt(n)` for `n > 4`.

Comment: If you're checking for prime factors of 1000001, you can save a lot of time by stopping at 1000 instead of 500000.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we are checking till `n/2` so that the number of iterations and the load on the system reduces and make the program more efficient. Since the greatest factor which can divide a number (excluding itself) is half of the number, we check only till that point. There is no point of checking beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

It's an attempt to improve the efficiency of the solution by stopping the loop at a point where the algorithm will no longer find any more prime factors.

However, it's suboptimal. If `n == a * b` and `a <= b`, `a` can be no higher than the square root of `n`. Therefore, checking for `i <= Math.sqrt(n)` would eliminate many more unnecessary iterations of the loop for large values of `n`.

A further improvement could be made by iterating over known values of `primes` instead of incremental values of `i`, since once you've established that a number isn't divisible by 3 there's no point checking 6, 9, 12 and so on.

Comment: *"A further improvement could be made by iterating over known values of primes"* That won't work here because of the `start` parameter.

Comment: You could address that by checking whether there are enough values of `primes` to satisfy the range and continuing to populate it until there are. Fair point though, since you'd be wasting time doing that if you wanted to check a range like 1000000000 to 1000000100.